# Expand selection to brackets in math mode doesn't work for LatexTools in sublimeText 2

Tags: latex, sublimetext2

Normally, the keyboard shortcut for expand selection to brackets, shift+ctrl+M, works great in the Latex environment for sublime text 2.  But for some reason, in math mode, it doesn't work.  It just does nothing.  Anyone know why, and how to fix it?

I've written a plugin which changes "( stuff )" to "\left( stuff \right)", but it requires the content between the brackets to be selected, so I really need this keyboard shortcut.  Please help!